# Specifying Tweepy API with sys.path.append( )

Tags: python, tweepy

Setup OSX 10.7.4 Eclipse Indigo, Pydev, Tweepy-1.9

I thought this should be relatively simple but I keep getting an error. I am looking to specify the Tweepy API using sys.path.append( ) However PyDev keeps showing me an "Unresolved  import: tweepy" Error

My Code

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/tweepy-1.9')
import tweepy
```

There are several similar posts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515686/django-sys-path-append-for-project-and-app-needed-under-wsgi) which I have looked at but they seem to give conflicting advice as to whether to link to the top level file or to a particular file within the directory.

**My question is** should I be linking directly to the top level folder as I am now (/Applications/tweepy-1.9) or to a particular file within this folder? Machaku provided me with some information on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11101619/1214163) saying I could do both but I would have to create a file named “**init**.py” and link to it.

I have tried both but neither seems to work.

Any suggestions as always are much appriciated

---

The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brendan/Documents/workspace/Tweeter/src/rate_limit.py", line 13, in <module>
    print api.rate_limit_status()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 149, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

---

tweepy-1.9 file structure

- tweepy-1.9

  - build

    - bdist.macosx-10.5-fat3
    - lib

      - tweepy

        - **init**.py *(with 2 underscores either side of "  init  ")*
        - api.py
        - auth.py
        - binder.py
        - cache.py
        - cursor.py
        - error.py
        - models.py
        - oauth.py
        - parsers.py
        - streaming.py
        - utils.py
  - dist

    - tweepy-1.9-py2.7.egg
  - PKG-INFO
  - README
  - setup.cfg
  - tweepy

    - **init**.py *(with 2 underscores either side of "  init  ")*
    - api.py
    - auth.py
    - binder.py
    - cache.py
    - cursor.py
    - error.py
    - models.py
    - oauth.py
    - parsers.py
    - streaming.py
    - utils.py
  - tweepy.egg-info

    - dependency_links.txt
    - PKG-INFO
    - SOURCES.txt
    - top_level.txt
    - zip_safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the stack trace, your Tweepy library is found, so your `sys.path.append` has worked. However, if you read the last line,

`tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

the error seems to be that the library cannot connect to the twitter service.

Concerning what to put in `sys.path`, it should be the folder that contains the directory where your top level package lives. So for example, if I have the following structure

```
src
 | my_package
 |     | __init__.py
 |     | module_1.py
 |     | module_2.py
```

and I want to be able to do `from my_package import module_1` then `sys.path` must contain the absolute path to `src`. Also, the `__init__.py` file must be present to make `my_package` a Python package.

However, dynamically updating `sys.path` is definitely not the recommended way to make python packages and modules accessible from another Python program.

There are much better solutions:

- calling `python setup.py install`, as recommended in the Tweepy [install guide](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/INSTALL) (preferably using a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv))
- updating PYTHONPATH to include the root path to the Tweety library.
- using `.pth` files that are read by the [site module](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site)

You can find more details in the Python doc on [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html) and in particular the [Modifying Python's search path section](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path)

Comment: Hey there, Thanks for the reply. Ill check this out in the morning when I have access to the code. I marked this as answered as you have shown that it is connecting. I suppose connecting to the top level folder as I did here works then.

Comment: @Deepend I have added some explanation regarding which folder should be present in `sys.path` for the import to subsequently work.